# meteorjs recommend way for count big collections depends on a value

Tags: collections, meteor

I have a problem with my performance on a pge in my meteorJs app.

The situation:
I have 2 Collections
- Business
- Categories

Business are items which have one or more categories.

Its build like this:

```
{
  _id : id,
  categories : [catid1, catid2, catid3],
  other data ...
}
```

On one page I display all categories and want to display how many Business-Items have the id of this category. I tested a few ways to do this the best way, but all ways have problems with the performance, so I am looking for a recommend way for this.

Currently I do it like this:

```
// server
Meteor.publish('allBusiness', function(){
    return Business.find({}, {reactive : false, fields : {_id:1,categories:1}});
});
// client
Meteor.subscribe('allBusiness');
```

In my Template, where the categories are shown up, I use this templatehelper:

```
// template
<li>{{name /* Name of Category*/}} ({{countBusiness _id/* Id of Category*/}})</li>


// handlebars helper
Handlebars.registerHelper('countBusiness', function(id) {
    return Business.find({ 
    categories : { $in : [id] } 
    }).fetch().length;

});
```

There are "just" about 1.000 Business-Items (a bit less than 1000) but my localhost needs about 1 minute to load, and when its loaded all is laggy. Is there a better way to solve this ?

Comment: Is the list of categories relatively small?

Comment: It has less than 300 items. Its about 290.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the data for `Business` entries, just their count, you shouldn't subscribe to them. That way you're sending all the data to the client, which will take time.

The easiest solution is to calculate the value on the server with a method:

```
var counts = {};
var countDep = new Deps.Dependency();

UI.registerHelpers({
  countBusiness: function(id) {
    countDep.depend();
    if(counts[id] === undefined) {
      Meteor.call('countBusiness', id, function(error, result) {
        counts[id] = result;
        countDep.changed();
      });
    }
    return counts[id];
  },
});
```

Now the server method. Here you should use `.count()` instead of `.fetch().length`, as the latter still needs time to fetch everything from the database.

```
Meteor.methods({
  countBusiness: function(id) {
    return Business.find({ 
      categories: id,
    }).count();
  },
});
```

A better, reactive solution would be to create a virtual collection with business count per category and subscribe to it. See `counts-by-room` example [here in the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) to see how it's done.

Comment: Thanks! This looks nice. Can you give me a ference site where I can see how this works ? I want to understand what I am doing. Why I need no subscribtion und publish anymore ?

Comment: Just ignore my question about the subscribtion and publish...its a server side method - forget it. :) thanks for this way of solution. Its more effective than mine!

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with Hubert's answer if you really don't want to denormalize your data. Depending on the size of your `Business` collection, that should work well, particularly if you have an index on `categories`. The downside is you are continually hitting your DB for a count which could have been pre-computed.

An alternative is just to keep a count of the number of `Business` documents in each `Categories` document. It reduces the DB load and scales nicely, but you will need to modify the appropriate category every time you modify a business.

If you go that route, you can use [collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks/) or just use a method whenever you update your `Business` documents.

Comment: I like this way of thinking. I will rebuild the process to do it this way and controll this counter with the insert/remove 'pre'call method by meteor